# material ui grid positioning confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, material-ui

I'm having trouble understanding the grid system in material UI. I have two grid items inside my grid container and I want them to both be centered and fill the full width of the grid container. The button element is centered, however the typography element is not.

Any ideas why ?

```html
<Grid container justify="center" allignItems="center">
  <Grid item xs={ 12}>
    <Typography>{props.currentUser} Account details</Typography>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item allignItems="center">
    <Button color="primary" variant={ "contained"} onClick={ ()=> props.logout()}>
              Log out
            </Button>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the document of `materialUI`,

`Typography` Component has `align` props.

so, you can do this

```
<Typography align="center">Account details</Typography>
```

ref:
https://material-ui.com/api/typography/#props

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not about `Grid` Component because it works perfectly.

Your Typography takes `100%` width of its parent which is `Grid` and then its content is by default `ltr` see the below description:

`Typography` Component by default `align`s its content based on `ltr` or `rtl` property of your `app` so if your `app` is `ltr` the `Typography` content align would be `left align`;

so if you need to change the Typography's content alignment you need to set `align` prop to `center`

```
<Grid container justify = "center" allignItems = "center">
          <Grid item xs = {12}>
            <Typography align='center'>{props.currentUser} Account details</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12} item allignItems = "center">
            <Button
              color = "primary" 
              variant = {"contained"} 
              onClick = {() => props.logout()}>
              Log out
            </Button>
          </Grid>
</Grid>
```